# app:backgroundTint has no effect on ViewGroup

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

I used a drawable xml file as my constraint layout background. now i want to change its color only for this layout.i used android:backgroundTint and it solved my problem. but my min sdk is 17 and android:backgroundTint need sdk 21 and higher, to solve that problem i used app:backgroundTint but it has no effect.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well android and app are just namespaces. "android" is the namespace for all the xml attributes that gets shipped with the specific android sdk api 21, 26... etc and "app" is the application defined namespace could be any name and is used to reference the attributes defined by the application, libraries including the support library if that attribute is not defined by either you or a library you are using then id does not do anything.

Comment: thanks for your comment. now in this case how can i do this work?

Comment: I am not aware of any way of doing this in xml. In code you can use ColorFilter, or just make another drawable with the different colour. Also in your shape do not use the namespace tool to set the colour, that namespace only sets attributes to preview in the IDE they do not get set in your apk.